# Different even and odd sorting in Quicksort

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I've got such an algorithmic problem: I need to make Quicksort to work like this:

1) Indexes of array which are odd numbers should be sorted from smallest to largest

2) Even indexes should be sorted from largest to smallest.

So if we've got array: 2 5 1 3 4 0 6 2 5,
we should get sth like: 6 0 5 2 4 3 2 5 1

Here is my implementation of quicksort in C:

```
    void quicksort(int tab[], int start, int end) {
    int i=start;
    int j=end;
    int x=tab[(i+j)/2];
    do {
        while(tab[i]<x) i++;
        while(tab[j]>x) j--;
        if(i<=j) {
            int tmp=tab[i];
            tab[i]=tab[j];
            tab[j]=tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while(i<=j);
    if(start<j) quicksort(tab,start,j);
    if(i<end) quicksort(tab,i,end);
    }
```

Is it possible to make it using just one quicksort or I should try sth like creating two functions: one will sort odd indexes and second one even indexes?

Comment: If all else fails, try writing two functions, then look how you can make them into one.

Comment: It seems to me it would be difficult to do both sorts at once, "in one go". Quicksort selects a pivot element, and then you split the data in two parts: elements that are smaller than the pivot, and those that are larger. Then sort those sets recursively. The set of "small, even" elements will not (necessarily) be of the same size of the set of "small, odd" elements, and the same for "large, even" and "large, odd". So the recursion will have to be done with different size sets for odd and even, with different "start" and "end" indices.

Comment: Just call qsort twice.

Comment: Call the original function twice but inside the function just play with index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make it using just one quicksort or I should try sth like creating two functions: one will sort odd indexes and second one even indexes?

- `quick sort` is generally used to sort elements in *ascending* or *descending* order so I don't think it'd be useful to just sort the elements in required pattern *( which is neither ascending nor descending and even no particular pattern is guaranteed in the answer array )* using only `quick sort`.

> In my opinion creating an additional custom function say `required_sort()` and sort elements as required along with the help of `qucksort()` *(here in my case it sorts in ascending order)* would be the best way to go

```
void required_sort(int array[], int size_of_array)
{
    int no_of_even_elements, no_of_odd_elements
    if(size_of_array%2 == 0)
    {
        no_of_even_elements = no_of_odd_elements = n/2;
    }    
    else
    {
        no_of_even_elements = (n/2)+1;
        no_of_odd_elements = n/2;     
    }

    int even[no_of_even_elements], odd_even[elements];

    //inserting elements into new arrays
    for(int index=0; index < size_of_array; index++)
    {
        if(index%2 == 0)
        {
            even[index/2] = array[index];
        }
        else
        { 
            odd[index/2] = array[index];
        }
    }

    //call quicksort function to sort the even[] array in ascending order
    //call quicksort function to sort the odd[] array in ascending order

    for(int index=0; index < size_of_array; index++)
    {
        if(index%2 == 0)
        {
            array[index] = even[(no_of_even_elements)-(index/2)];
        }
        else
        {
           array[index] = odd[index/2];
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Explanation** of `required_sort` :

- first check whether `size_of_array` is *even* or *odd*
- if `size_of_array` is *even* then there are equal number of elements at odd indices and even indices. so

  ```
  no_of_even_elements = no_of_odd_elements = n/2
  ```
- if `size_of_array` is *odd* then there are equal number of elements at odd indices and even indices. so

  ```
  no_of_even_elements = (n/2)+1
  no_of_odd_elements = n/2
  ```
- create two more arrays. say `odd[no_of_odd_elements]` and `even[no_of_even_elements]`
- in first array store the elements at *odd* indices and in the second the elements at *even* indices.
- use `quicksort()` *(in ascending order)* to sort both the arrays
- now using a `for` loop to update the values of original `array[]` this way :

  ```
  for(int index=0; index < size_of_array; index++)
  {
      if(index%2 == 0)
      {
          array[index] = even[(no_of_even_elements)-(index/2)];
      }
      else
      {
         array[index] = odd[index/2];
      }
  }
  ```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize your quicksort algorithm in order to support (1) partial sorting based on a step size and (2) the sorting direction.

```
void quicksort2(int tab[], int start, int end, int step, int (*comparer)(int, int))
```

1. introducing a parameter `step` that is used to access elements that are `step` elements away from `start` and `end`

   Whenever an index is changed, use step size instead of `1`: `i+=step;`, `j-=step;` and so on.

   Computing the middle element for pivot becomes slightly more complex in order to support uneven indices with step size > 1: `int mid = (end / step - start / step) / 2 * step + start; int x=tab[mid];`

   The `start` and `end` index are required to be a multiple of `step` apart.
2. changing the comparison to a `comparer` function instead of native `<` and `>` operator usage

   The comparer function is expected to return negative values for `a < b` and positive values for `b < a`. Usage: `while(comparer(tab[i],x) < 0) // ...`

Putting it all together:

```
void quicksort(int tab[], int start, int end, int step, int (*comparer)(int, int))
{
    int i=start;
    int j=end;
    int mid = (end / step - start / step) / 2 * step + start;
    int x=tab[mid];
    do {
        while(comparer(tab[i],x) < 0) i+=step;
        while(comparer(tab[j],x) > 0) j-=step;
        if(i<=j) {
            int tmp=tab[i];
            tab[i]=tab[j];
            tab[j]=tmp;
            i+=step;
            j-=step;
        }
    } while(i<=j);
    if(start<j) quicksort(tab,start,j, step, comparer);
    if(i<end) quicksort(tab,i,end, step, comparer);
}
```

I tried to stick close to your initial native quicksort implementation, so this code should look pretty familiar.

This can be used to execute the desired sorting as follows:

Define comparer functions for ascending and descending sortings.

```
int smaller(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int bigger(int a, int b)
{
    return b - a;
}
```

And call quicksort twice for the two sub-sortings

```
int values[] = { 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 6, 2, 5 };
quicksort(values, 0, 8, 2, &smaller);
quicksort(values, 1, 7, 2, &bigger);
```

Be careful to get the start and end indices right or add a sanity check for them inside the quicksort function